# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for Pi3

Tags: raspberrypi

I'm still struggling to get Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Pi3. Official images don't work. Where did you find the image: ubuntu-minimal-16.04-server-armhf-raspberry-pi.img.xz? Or, have you found a different 16.04 LTS image that works?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [link](http://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/) and the **ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz** image got properly installed in Raspberry pi 3. One thing to note is that it is a server image so no UI will be there by default.

I took an empty SD card and then use the instructions mentioned in the same page for **"Making a microSDHC"**. After rebooting it started with ubuntu with kernel version **4.4.0-1009-raspi2**.